# Jenkins DSL for ci-skip plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to configure the [ci-skip plugin](https://github.com/banyan/jenkins-ci-skip-plugin) in a Jenkins DSL job.

Since this plugin is not supported, I've written this configure block:

```
mavenJob("testproject") {
  #...
  wrappers {
    configure { node ->
      node / 'buildWrappers' / 'ruby-proxy-object' / 'ruby-object'(['ruby-class': 'Jenkins::Tasks::BuildWrapperProxy', 'pluginid': 'ci-skip']) {
        'object'(['ruby-class': 'CiSkipWrapper', 'pluginid': 'ci-skip']) {
          'ci__skip'(['ruby-class': 'NilClass', 'pluginid': 'ci-skip'])
        }
        'pluginid'([pluginid: 'ci-skip', 'ruby-class': 'String'], 'ci-skip')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This correctly generates the XML:

```
<buildWrappers>
    <ruby-proxy-object>
        <ruby-object ruby-class="Jenkins::Tasks::BuildWrapperProxy" pluginid="ci-skip">
            <object ruby-class="CiSkipWrapper" pluginid="ci-skip">
                <ci__skip ruby-class="NilClass" pluginid="ci-skip"/>
            </object>
            <pluginid ruby-class="String" pluginid="ci-skip">ci-skip</pluginid>
        </ruby-object>
    </ruby-proxy-object>
</buildWrappers>
```

But in the end, the plugin is not enabled... The checkbox in "Build environment" for "Enable ci-skip" is unchecked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue is documented here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38145

Downgrading from Ruby Runtime Plugin 0.13 to 0.12 resolves this!